# $scope is not working on my angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

can't display `yo homie` in my view and idk why.

here's a github repo https://github.com/homiepotato/-scope-not-working

**note**: this is my master page where all my javascript lib located at

### my view (master.html)

```
 <html ng-app='potato'>
<div ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
<div id='menu' class="pure-u-1">
    {{s_master}}     
</div>
</div>
<div ng-view=''></div> <!-- this is where main.html inject-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/javascripts/controllers.js"></script>

</html>
```

### /static/javascripts/app.js

```
   var potato = angular.module('potato',['ngRoute','ngCookies']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/static/views/main.html',
    controller: 'IndexCtrl'
  }).
  when('/login',{
    templateUrl: '/static/views/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  }).
  when('/register',{
    templateUrl: '/static/views/register.html',
    controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
  })
      /* some route and controller but the MasterCtrl is not  included */
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

### /static/javascripts/controllers.js

```
 // controller for master.html(the master page)
function MasterCtrl($scope, $http, $cookies) {
  $scope.s_master = "yo homie" 
 /* the $scope is not working on this controller
    but other function work fine like $cookies $http
    the rest of the controller work fine but not MasterCtrl 
 */
}
// controller for main.html
function IndexCtrl($scope, $http) {

}
// controller for login.html
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.form = {};
  $scope.errorMessage='';
  $scope.submitLogin = function() {
    $http.post('/login',$scope.form).
      success(function(data){
        $location.path('/');
      }).error(function(err){
        $scope.errorMessage = err;
      });
  }
}
// controller for register.html
function RegisterCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.form = {};
    $scope.errorMessage = '';
  $scope.submitPost = function() {
    $http.post('/register', $scope.form).
      success(function(data) {
        $location.path('/');
      }).error(function(err) {
        $scope.errorMessage = err;
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: The problem is the "yo homie" bit.  Angular doesn't speak street.

Comment: first question: are you sure you don't get any error anywhere? second you're missing a ";" after the string (hopefully is just a type error XD ) third, really with all the string yo homie????? XDDDDDD

Comment: Is your javascript file where your controller is defined referenced in your html (like the way you have reference your angularjs files) , unless you have defined it between <script> in your html?

Comment: :D, hi @Sakuya84 thanks for your reply i thought semicolon is optional and there's no error showing up in my browser console literally nothing

Comment: @Potato Yeah, semicolons in JavaScript are actually optional ;) there is no error in that part

Comment: Open **<body>** tag :)

Comment: @DumitruChirutac just some left over code pretty sure that's not the error :D

Comment: Can you reproduce the error on jsfiddle or plnkr ? I'm not sure anyone can help you otherwise, as the code you posted all seems OK.

Comment: Try putting your js scripts into <head></head> tags - Also have a look at the javascript console for errors

Comment: @ccheneson tried, i still can't display it on master.html, it works fine on other controller but not the MasterCtrl

Comment: Try removing $http, $cookies from the controller's parameter

Comment: @ccheneson i still have the same result, i can do alert from the controller or even get the cookies object by using the $cookies but only the $scope is not working on it but it work fine on other controller in my controller.js

Comment: and you have nothing in the javascript console?

Comment: @ccheneson yes i have nothing on my console

Comment: hey guys i just create a repo, maybe you can check it out if you have the time https://github.com/homiepotato/-scope-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checked the code it caused by

```
app.get('*',function(req, res){
  res.render('master');
});
```

because of `res.render`client side can't get the $scope value just change it to

```
app.get('*',function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('./public/views/master.html');
});
```

Comment: I fail to see how this is related - both work in an identical way, and the `render` call does not affect the client side in any way at all.

Comment: yes it does because he is trying to render master page at serverside , just download the code and try my solution

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are not showing all your code, you are missing "ng-app".

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MasterCtrl">
```

Comment: but i have <html ng-app='potato'> does it count ?

Comment: var potato = angular.module('potato',['ngRoute','ngCookies']).

Comment: Maybe show all your code?  Where is the "var potato" code located?  Also, as Sakuya84 asked, are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: hey i just created a repo for this problem , maybe you can check it out if you have the time https://github.com/homiepotato/-scope-not-working

Comment: The repo works fine for me (I had to disable the mongodb stuff as I don't have a server to test against).  I get this: http://d.pr/i/4YDr

Answer (score 0):

Where is **ng-app** attribute ?

Your HTML should look like this:

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MasterCtrl">

  <div id="menu" class="pure-u-1">
     {{s_master}}
  </div>

</div>
```

And Javascript:

```
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

  app.controller('MasterCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.s_master = "yo homie";

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted, I've put it up at http://plnkr.co/edit/D7qpi4j4gYn2l4Kqd74X?p=preview and it runs as you'd expect.

Maybe there's another part of your code you haven't posted that's causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.js` is pretty much entirely broken.  You have:

- No reference to `$routeProvider` for the `when` function calls
- A trailing `.` on the end of the final `when`

You should see some errors in your JavaScript console.

Try correcting your `app.js` to read something like:

```
 var potato = angular.module('potato', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']).
 config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
      templateUrl: '/static/views/main.html',
      controller: 'IndexCtrl'
    }).
    when('/login',{
      templateUrl: '/static/views/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }).
    when('/register',{
      templateUrl: '/static/views/register.html',
      controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
    })

    /* some route and controller but the MasterCtrl is not  included */
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

As @DumitruChirutac suggests, I would also urge you not to use the 'global' naming of controllers, but define them on your app module instead.

Working plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gcieHTrw50AnWPZVzQNL?p=preview

Comment: Why is it better to define them on the app module?  I actually put my controllers in a separate file as well.  Is this a bad practice?

Comment: Polluting the global namespace is always bad practice. Angular provides modules to allow us not to perform this pollution.  A separate file is fine (I have a separate file for every controller), but IMHO it's better to keep everything out of the global namespace wherever possible.